# Why isn't my onScroll event firing on child elements react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child and a parent element.

the css is the following:

```
.parent {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

I have an 'onScroll' event linstener on the parent element which works perfectly.
But If I add an 'onScroll' event linster to the child element, the event doesn't fire...
Interestingly I've noticed that the event on the parent element doesn't fire either if I remove the 'height': 100vh' property. So I add the same height property to the child but it still does not work.

What I'd like to do is firing the scroll event on the child element without having to deal with the parent. How can I achieve this?

parent:

```
    function App() {
      return (
            <BrowserRouter>
              <div className="app" onScroll={onScroll} this fires>
                {(menuToggled)?<Menu menuToggled={menuToggled} 
    closesMenu={closesMenu}/>:null}
                <Nav handlesMenuBtn={handlesMenuBtn} />
                  <Routes>
                      <Route path='/' element={<Home />}></Route>
                      <Route path='/about' element={<About/>}></Route>
                      <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact/>}></Route>
                      <Route path='/projects' element= 
    <Projects/>}></Route>
                  </Routes>
                  <Footer />
              </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
          )
        }
```

child:

```
function Projects() {
   
    useEffect(() => {
    })

    return (
        <div className="projects-menu" onScroll={()=>{console.log("working")}} this doesn't fire>
            <div className="projects-menu-container">
                <div className="big-letters-container">
                    <p className='super-big-letters-about' style={{color: 'rgba(255, 164, 0, 0.5)'}}> PROJECTS</p>
                    <p className="big-letters" style={{zIndex: '1'}}>
                        PROJECTS
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div className="project-container">
                    <Project />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Post your JS/React code.

Comment: @Dai I just uploaded my codes. Please could you have a look?? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Hello other possibility is to use stopPropagation, like this:

```
function Projects() {
  useEffect(() => {});

  const handleScroll = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
  };

  return (
    <div className="projects-menu" onScroll={handleScroll}>
      <div className="projects-menu-container">
        <div className="big-letters-container">
          <p
            className="super-big-letters-about"
            style={{ color: "rgba(255, 164, 0, 0.5)" }}
          >
            {" "}
            PROJECTS
          </p>
          <p className="big-letters" style={{ zIndex: "1" }}>
            PROJECTS
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="project-container">
          <Project />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

More information about propagation and bubling phases.https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_stoppropagation.asp

Answer (score 0):

The `scroll` event only works on scrollable elements; like a `div` with a fixed height, or the `window` itself (Just see if the element has a scrollbar or not).

This works:

```
<div className="scrollable-div" onScroll={changeButtonColor}>
    <button>I will change on scroll</button>
</div>
```

This doesn't:

```
<div className="scrollable-div">
    <button onScroll={changeButtonColor}>I will not change on scroll</button>
</div>
```